# How to overlay multiple plots on the same graph in Stata?

Tags: data-visualization, stata

I am using the [following code](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/19759) for drawing a plot on a graph in Stata. I want to draw multiple plots on the same graph. Is that possible? Can anyone kindly tell me what to do?

What I want to do is to have multiple plots of the following types in the same graph.

**Further clarification:** There will be multiple means and CIs for each value of X, i.e. one mean and CI for each simulation model. All the means and CIs for one simulation model will be connected together.

```
    clear 
    input str2 varname mean upper lower
    x1 30 25  35
    x2 50 20  80
    x3 60 50  70
    x4 60 55  65
    x5 65 55  75
    end

    encode varname, gen(varname1)   
    scatter mean varname1, xlabel(, valuelabel) || rcap upper lower varname1 || line upper mean lower varname1
```

Comment: You'll have to give us more detail. Are you trying to combine several different plots? Your second example is a superset of the first. Please tell us exactly which plots you are hoping to draw on the same graph.

Comment: @pmgjones : sorry for the typo in the code. What I want to do is have two of these plots in the same graph. is that possible in stata ?

Comment: That plot *already* overlaps three different plots (`scatter` for the dots, `rcap` for the vertical lines, and `line` for the horizontal lines).  Just keep on going with the command, adding in each part you want to overlay.  If you want them side-by-side instead of overlaid, read the help for `graph combine`.

Comment: @whuber : thanks for the kind suggestions..it worked. I am new to Stata...thats why was having trouble figuring out what to do....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @whuber kindly mentioned, we need to use `||` to draw more things. I used the following code to draw more than one plot of the type I need on the same graph. Thanks.

```
    clear 
    input str2 varname mean upper lower
    x1 30 25  35
    x2 50 20  80
    x3 60 50  70
    x4 60 55  65
    x5 65 55  75
    end

    encode varname, gen(varname1)

    input str4 varname4 mean4 upper4 lower4
    x1 40 35  45
    x2 60 30  90
    x3 70 60  80
    x4 70 65  75
    x5 75 65  85

    scatter mean varname1, xlabel(, valuelabel) || rcap upper lower varname1 || line upper mean lower varname1 ||scatter mean4 varname1, xlabel(, valuelabel)  || rcap upper4 lower4 varname1  ||  line upper4 mean4 lower4 varname1
```