# overlaying graph in stata 13

Tags: graph, stata

I am a new stata 13 user and I would like to learn how to overlay results from several experiments.

I have 1000 curves (id_1 id_2.. id_100 ) each curve has the same "x" but not the same "y" and I would like to plot all the curves togheter like a "spaghetti plot".
I have done it -  manually:-(  -for 100 curves (attached) but I hope there is a way do it automatically! thanks for your help, Matteo

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Update: How to overlay up to 1,500 curves "automatically"**

Nick  Cox noted that my previous answer, below, didn't answer the original question because Stata's `twoway scatter` graphics command will not accept 100 plot variables. (I discovered that it will  accept up to 99). However one *can* overlay more than 100 curves by linking multiple `twoway` graph commands (See page 178 of the Stata 13 Graphics Manual).  Below I switch to `twoway connect`, because `twoway scatter` requires a `connect()` option if you want to connect points.

So:

```
twoway (connect p1-p50 x) (connect p51-p100 x)
```

will overlay 100 curves.

However the original poster's example makes it clear that he wants to overlay *smooth* curves, whereas `twoway connect` will show marker symbols for each plotted point.  The only way to avoid seeing the symbols is to specify that they be invisible.  I did this in the previous answer with the `msymbol()` option  (`ms()` for short).  However `msymbol()` has a limit of 20 arguments. With larger numbers of series, therefore, one needs to accumulate `connect` statements of 20 or fewer predictors each. This means that one can no longer use the convenient `p*` varlist to specify the variable list of predictors.

With 100 curves, for example, it is necessary to write out the five connect statements with sequential blocks of 20 numbered predictors . This grows very tedious and, from personal experience, can be quite error-prone. Moreover, although the question spoke of 100 or 1,000 curves, one cannot always count on such conveniently round numbers.

Below, I use local macros to construct the single `twoway` statement. In the example I assume that there are 108 series, 107 with 10 observations, the last one with five. There will be 108 plot variables py1-py108, and six connect statements will be needed, <s>four</s> **five** with 20 series each and the last one with eight.

Here is the contents of the final plot statement, contained in the macro `plot_command`. I've broken the lines for readability.

```
twoway (connect(py1 - py20  x, ms(i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i)))     
(connect(py21 - py40  x, ms(i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i)))    
(connect(py41 - py60  x, ms(i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i))) 
(connect(py61 - py80  x, ms(i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i))) 
(connect(py81-py88 x, ms(i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i)) ) , legend(off)
```

.

The maximum number of curves possible is 1,500, a limit (somewhat arbitrary) imposed by the `separate` command.

```
 clear

 set obs 1075
 gen int id = ceil(_n/10)  /* original id */

/* IDs might not be consecutive integers, and might also not be numeric.
   Therefore, create a new id consisting of consecutive integers starting with 1 */

  egen idnew = group(id)
 /* get total number of ids */
  sum idnew
  local n_ids = r(max)
  di `n_ids'

/*number of connect statements needed */

  local csecs = ceil(`n_ids'/20)
  di `csecs'


/* Data for plotting */
gen x = rnormal()
gen py = id + x /*variable to plot for each series*/

*****************************
 sort py id // crucial for plotting
*****************************
qui separate py, by(id)


/* Construct local macros to build up the twoway statement */

/* macro "mspart" will contain the msymbol option
   It will contain 20 "i"'s which will not cause
   an error even if the number of plot variables is
   < 20 */


 local mspart = " ms(i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i)"

/* Start each connect command */
 local cstart = "(connect "

/* Construct the connect statement for for consecutive blocks of 20 series.  */
 forvalues i = 1/`=`csecs'-1'{
    local c1_`i' = ///
    "`cstart'"+"py" +string(20*(`i'-1)+1) +" - py"+string(20*(`i'-1)+20)
    local c1_`i' =  "`c1_`i''" + "  x, " + "`mspart'"+") "
    }

/* Construct one more connect statement for the remaining series */
 local extra = mod(`n_ids',20)

 if `extra' == 0 {
     local extra = 20
     }
       local c1_`csecs'= ///
     "`cstart'" + "py"+string(20*(`csecs'-1)+1) + "-py"+string(20*(`csecs'-1)+`extra')+" x, "+"`mspart'"+ ") "


/* Now put all the connect statements into one macro */
forvalues i = 1/`csecs' {
    local com = "`com'"  + "`c1_`i''"
    }

/* Finish the twoway statement */
local plot_command = "twoway " +"`com'" + ", legend(off)"
di "`plot_command'"

/* Get the plots */

`plot_command'
```

**Original Post**

Although, you have not provided code on which to base an answer, the question is an interesting one, so I'll provide a solution. You'll have to adapt this to your problem. There was a similar question on StackOverlow  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591067/how-to-overlay-multiple-plots-on-the-same-graph-in-stata), but the answer did not address the automation part of your question.  In what follows, I use the standard system  auto data set.  I create an `id` variable from the `rep78` variable; use `mpg` as the "y" variable and `turn` as the "x". If there is a command that you don't understand, look it up in the `help`. Note that "///" connects two lines. See "help comment"

```
sysuse auto, clear

/* Create a numeric id variable that starts with "1" and is numbered
   consecutively */
egen id = group(rep78)

/* get count of id from -summarize- output*/
sum id
local n_id = r(max)   /* local macro */
di "Number of ids is: `n_id'"

/* Create a response for
```

---

Comment: This will be very helpful to many but leaves untouched the question of what you do with 100 or 1000 series (the original question is unclear, but there is problem either way) as `graph` will not accept that many variables. I would be more inclined to work at an answer if there was some effort made to improve the question.

Comment: I agree. We really don't know enough about the data or what the poster has done in Stata so far.